# Opto Coupler output voltage drop when connected to PLC

Tags: opto-isolator, plc

I have an input of pulse width 5 ms and which is fed to a Buffer IC and then the output of the buffer is FED to an opto isolator whose collector is pulled with a pull up of 7.5k resistor with an 24 V source. When no load is connected the output is fine but when connected to a load (PLC input pin) The output drops to 10V.

We increased the pull up to 15K the output is the same.

The opto used here is a 4N35

Please suggest some points to TAP on and a solution for the same.

Thank you

Comment: Increasing the pullup resistance will make it worse, not better.

Comment: Okey then what should be done to avoid this?

Comment: Name names. Doesn't the PLC have a datasheet?

Comment: What does FED and TAP stand for?

Answer (score 2):

Your PLC may have an opto-coupler on its input which is connected to 'ground' (common terminal) and needs to be pulled *up* by your opto-coupler. If so then you should wire the Collecter to +24V, and the Emitter to the PLC input. A pull-down resistor may not be necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Schematic for @Bruce Abbott's answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7nfO8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Opto isolator interface to PLC 'sinking' input.*